# Are Bluemix Container Volumes encrypted

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud

Is the data in Bluemix container volumes encrypted?

The volumes are hosted on fileshares, but I can't find any information whether its encrypted by default or I have to specify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bluemix containers volumes are not encrypted by default ,but users can  encrypt and save there data to Object Storage